# Fedora 30 - Laptop screen is flickering

Tags: fedora, display, thinkpad

I have a small problem with my Thinkpad T480s. After I updated it from Fedora 29 to 30, and an external screen is connected to it, my laptop screen flickers sometimes. Note that I use XORG instead of Wayland.

I've tried several things already:

1. I tried to install the latest stable kernel from Vanilla `5.1.9-350.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64`
2. Added these options in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in the file `/etc/default/grub`: `intel_iommu=on,igfx_off i915.enable_psr=0 i915.enable_rc6=0`. And updated the GRUB by using `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.
3. I also did an BIOS update to version 1.31.

All these things didn't work.

For information, DMESG: `[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun`